# Prove that the linear space of polynomials with root $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that linear space of polynomials having root $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]_n$.
It's also required to find basis and dim of that subspace.

I recently started learning linear algebra on my own and generally got what problem is about, but I believe I'm still lack of practice.

**My attempt**
$\mathbb{R}[x]_n$ would be a vector space of polynomials with characteristic $= n$.
Let's look on the specific case:
Say $char = 3$ then pick some polynomial $2n^3-n=0$ We solve it and assume  $\alpha =\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$.
It's easy to see that $2n^2-1=0$ would have root $\alpha$ as well.
And generally any polynomial multiplied by $(2n^2-1)$ would have it.
My next idea was to look at this subspace as an algebra, but than I realized that subspace should be closed just under scalar multiplication, so we don't need that.
Then for this specific case, basis would be $\{e_k,e_{k+2}\}$, where:
 $e_k=\{0,0,...-1,0,0...0\}$
 $e_{k+2}=\{0,0,...,0,0,2,0...0\}$
Clearly, cardinality of that subspace would be 2.
But I'm not sure about correctness of everything written above. And what more important, I'm failing to generalize.

I don't need a complete solution for this one, since it's possible that I will not understand it and because my main purpose is learning.
So I would appreciate some hints and pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Is $\Bbb R[x]_n$ the set of real polynomials of degree no greater than $n$?  That is, $p(x) \in \Bbb R[x]_n \Leftrightarrow \deg p \le n$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Actually, it's up to us to decide, task has just this symbolic notation. The source of the task has no attached textbook or something to look up what their notation means.
Your interpretation has right to live, but I read it in another fashion: possible polynomial degree has no upperbound, but n stands for characteristic of field. Like residue field modulo $n$.

Comment: Show that if $f$ has root $\alpha$ and $g$ has root $\alpha$, then $af+bg$ has root $\alpha$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @wf34:  OK, thanks, I'll think on this one . . . ;-)

Comment: @wf34 I doubt that your alternative interpretation is valid, after all $\mathbb R$ has characteristic $0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe I'm out of my depth here, but I disagree. We have here vector space of polynomials over field $\mathbb{R}$.  It's possible thing to have the vector space of polynomials with modular arithmetic. Isn't that right? I saw similiar problems few years ago.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Another motivation of my objections - I saw similar notation in one algebra book, which is popular in our country. This notion $A[x]_n$ meant residue field there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $\Bbb R[x]_n$ is the subspace of $\Bbb R[x]$ consisting of the polynomials whose degree is $\leq n$. Note that $\{1,x,\dotsc,x^n\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R[x]_n$ so $\dim(\Bbb R[x]_n)=n+1$.

Now, let $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and let
$$
V=\{f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]_n:f(\alpha)=0\}
$$
To see that $V$ is a subspace, let $f,g\in V$ and let $a,b\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$
(a\cdot f+b\cdot g)(\alpha)=a\cdot f(\alpha)+b\cdot g(\alpha)=?
$$
Can you finish the computation to show that $V$ is a subspace?

Next, to find a basis for $V$, note that
$$
\{(x-\alpha),\dotsc,(x-\alpha)^n\}
$$
is a linearly independent collection in $\Bbb R[x]_n$ whose elements are in $V$. This means that $\dim(V)\leq n$. Can you use this information to find $\dim V$?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a polynomial with $f(\alpha)=0$ then $f$ can be written as $f(x)=(x-\alpha) g(x)$ (use polynomial division). We conclude that the linear map $\mathbb R[x]_{n-1}\to \mathbb R[x]_n$, $g\mapsto (x-\alpha)g$ induces an isomorphism with the subset in question.
By this we automatically have that it is a subspace, has the same dimension as  $\mathbb R[x]_{n-1}$, and that the image of a basis, such as  $\{(x-\alpha)x^k\}_{0\le k\le n-1}$ form a basis.